# All or None with SQLMetal?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sqlmetal

I was looking to create a pre-build method for a web application using SQLMetal to bring any changes since the last build into my DBML file.  Since we are just starting out with LINQ most of the large database is not in the DBML.  Is there any way to use SQLMetal to just regenerate a handful (less than 10) of tables and about 3 SPROCs or is it all or none?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, unfortunately.  I'm trying to figure out a good way to do it myself.

Some interesting links discussing this problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx (see the comments at the bottom)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/a36bde81-3376-40a4-8b99-49b403b60e60/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/7604ea59-fab9-4763-93fb-589d5ff959a0/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use powershell this will remove the tables you do not want.

http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-power-of-powershell-to-configure.html